# AceGen: User element generation for FEAP or ABAQUS to solve coupled problems

Tags: acegen

Is possible to generate elements (SKR module) to use in FEAP or Abaqus for problems involving additional degrees of freedom?

I'm trying to generate an 3D element to establish the mechanical equilibrium of a problem involving coupling between displacements $\mathbf{u}$ and the field $\psi$)

[image: Strong form of the BVP: coupled problem]

Comment: Are you looking for elements with coupled physical fields, like displacement and temperature field? It is possible to generate (SKR) subroutines for such elements for different environments (FEAP, ABAQUS, etc) with recent versions of AceFEM (6.816). Use the the interactive panel by clicking "AceShare"->"Main Library"->"Select element"->...->"Generate element".

Comment: @Pinti. That's exactly the physical coupling I was looking for: coupled temperature-displacements problems. Using the interactive panel for element generation I was able to generate an element for FEAP/Abaqus environment. However, the generation led to an element with 24 dof and 16 nodes (8 for displacements and 8 for temperature). I was hoping to obtain an element with 8 nodes and 32 dof.

Comment: Are you sure that you chose correct topology and other settings? Maybe you could edit your question and add more details about what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This [PhD](http://drugg.fgg.uni-lj.si/5444/) thesis about coupled problems in AceGen could be useful for you. Unfortunately it is written in Slovenian language, but there are plenty of code snippets and examples inside.

Comment: @Pinti, The PhD thesis partially solved my problem. Unfortunately, the use of SKR AceGen module still bring some limitations, especially for the type of problems I've exposed. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Pinti, can we use Acegen for multiphase field problems, e.g. solidification, we have at least 5 fields??

Comment: @ABCDEMMM Probably yes, number of nodal DOF is not limited.

Comment: @Pinti, what means "Probably " in acefem/acegen??

Comment: @ABCDEMMM It means "yes", but I haven't tried it myself. I suggest that you start experimenting with the simplest possible examples and then build your models from there.

Comment: @Pinti, it seems not so that easy, at least we have to solve C1 problem in Acegen (Cahn Hillard problems).

Comment: @ABCDEMMM I am not familiar with this type of problems, but it seems that [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0045782518303396) paper describes phase-field modelling with AceGen.

Comment: @Pinti, thanks a lot! I will try  to build a Cahn Hillard Model in ACEGEN, I hope that I can solve C1 problems........

Comment: @ABCDEMMM Maybe I can give you a few more tips about this. If you wish, you can contact me on `Uncompress["1:eJxTTMoPChZjYGDITSzJzgcThoYO6bmJmTl6yfm5AJItCf8="]`.

Comment: @Pinti, how to use Uncompress[...]?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM Just evaluate the whole expression in MMA, it returns a string with my email.